# Get Linkedin user details using application details in php

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am working on webservices and I have a scenario in which I have to get user details from user id sent to server from ios .

Till now what I am getting is that I can get user details only if I redirect user to accept the access and then get the user details from the access token I got. I want to know if there is any way by which I can get the details on the behalf of the application  without making user to actually accept the access ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want, i don`t understant your question. You want to take user data without accepting an conection to your server ??

Comment: I want to know if I can get user details for ID on the behalf of application as we can do in facebook ?